# Does Superman age the same as us?

Tags: dc, superman, krypton

Do the Kryptonians have the same life expectancy as humans?

Does their life expectancy differ while being on Earth?

We see Superman go from childhood to adulthood quite normally but does it mean he moves to old age the same as us?

Is there a difference between the duration of his adulthood and ours as he seems to have a similar adolescence??

Comment: Well he's barely changed since 1938 so I'd say, no, he doesn't age. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5a/Action_Comics_1.jpg

Comment: That is my question exactly. He came to Earth as a child and grew up to be an adult(Superman) so this does suggest that he ages... But does he ages after adulthood is what i am asking?

Comment: Which canon might matter here. In [DC 1 Million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_One_Million), he's still alive and lives in the sun 85,000 years from now, so apparently at that point he was immortal.

Comment: @Paul Any canon that supports his mortality!

Comment: My thoughts were he aged normally until he got to the fortress of solitude, then he was "locked in" at that age. That's why been the same since the 1930's. The bigger question is, how does he get his hair cut?

Comment: @DanShaffer: Laser vision reflected off a mirror?